# Custom list of environments (per section)

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, environments

I'd like to have a list of my custom environments at the start of each section. I read [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12510/how-do-i-create-custom-list-of-s-on-a-section-level), but wasn't able to get the titletoc to help me. The given response worked for floats, but I couldn't see how to adapt it to (non-floating) environments.

Here is a MWE of what I have so far; it works the way I want to, except for the spacing issues between the commas. It follows along the lines of the discussion in the above post, by creating a file for each section (hacked from the ntheorem package).

So, my questions are: how could I fix the spacing issues between the commas? Is it bad to create lots of auxiliary files (.prb1, .prb2, etc)? Have I re-invented a wheel? I'd also welcome any other feedback.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcounter{probfilecounter}
\setcounter{probfilecounter}{0}
\newcounter{index}
\newcounter{linecount}
\newread\File

\let\stdsection\section
\renewcommand\section{\stepcounter{probfilecounter}\stdsection}

\makeatletter

\def\listproblems{%
\openin\File=\jobname.prb\thesection%
%\@input{\jobname .prb\thesection}%
\setcounter{linecount}{0}%
\loop\unless\ifeof\File%
\stepcounter{linecount}%
\read\File to\fileline %
\repeat%
\closein\File%
% re-open the file
\setcounter{index}{0}%
\openin\File=\jobname.prb\thesection%
\loop\unless\ifeof\File%
\stepcounter{index}% 
\read\File to\fileline%
%\fileline
    \ifthenelse{\theindex=1}%
    {Problems in this section: \fileline}%
    {%
    \ifthenelse{\theindex<\thelinecount}%
    {, \fileline}%
    {}%
    }%
\repeat%
\closein\File%
}%

\def\prb@enablelistofproblems{%
\begingroup%
\makeatletter%
\if@filesw%
\setcounter{index}{0}%
\whiledo{\value{index}<\theprobfilecounter}{%
\stepcounter{index}% 
\expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@prb\theindex\endcsname%
\immediate\openout \csname tf@prb\theindex\endcsname \jobname.prb\theindex\relax%
 }%
\fi%
\@nobreakfalse%
\endgroup}%

\AtEndDocument{\prb@enablelistofproblems}

\makeatother

% define the problem environment
\newcounter{problem}
\newenvironment{problem}{
    \refstepcounter{problem}%
    \textbf{Problem \theproblem} \par
    \addtocontents{prb\theprobfilecounter}{\theproblem}
}{}

\begin{document}

\section{intro}
\listproblems

\begin{problem}
 second problem
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
 another problem
\end{problem}

\section{another section}
\listproblems

\begin{problem}
 another problem
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
 another problem
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the line endings in your `.prb<number>` files are translated into spaces by TeX. If I change the code line

```
    {, \fileline}%
```

to

```
    {\unskip, \fileline}%
```

the spaces before the commas disappear.

Comment: Thanks again @lockstep. I think I've come to an answer about my question of the .prb1, .prb2, ... files- if I have too many, there's, 'No room for a new \write'. Guess it's time to get more resourceful!

Comment: @smr01cmh: You're welcome! BTW, don't forget to upvote my answer as soon as you have enough reputation to do so. ;-)

Comment: Will do! I'm currently only at 8!

Answer (score 2):

I had tried your approach but had two problems.  One is that it's not really compatible with using `\include` and `\includeonly` to fragment the document and only compile parts of it at a time.  If you have Section 1 and Section 2 in different files, and have problem files `foo.prb1` and `foo.prb2`, then exclude the first section's file, you need to also tell the second section (which is now the first section read) to look in file `foo.prb2`.  Or something like that.  I ended up with lists in the wrong section.

The other thing is that TeX has a limit to the number of files it can have open at once.  I believe that number is 16.  So unless you close each of the `.prb<n>` files you will quickly run out (my document has 15 chapters and close to 100 sections).

Here's how I adapted [Leo's answer to the linked question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12510/how-do-i-create-custom-list-of-s-on-a-section-level/12514#12514) to my document and your example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titletoc}


\newcounter{problem}
\newenvironment{problem}{
    \refstepcounter{problem}%
    \noindent\textbf{Problem \theproblem} \par
    \addcontentsline{prb}{subsection}{Problem \theproblem}
}{}

\makeatletter%\begin{hack}
\def\ttl@partialprb{ppr}
\def\ttl@writepartial#1#2{%
  \ttl@topartial{toc}{#1}{#2}%
  \ttl@topartial{lof}{#1}{#2}%
  \ttl@topartial{lot}{#1}{#2}%
  \ttl@topartial{prb}{#1}{#2}%
  \ttl@writefile{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother%\end{hack}


\newcommand{\listproblems}{
  \startlist{prb}%
  \printlist{prb}{}{\subsection*{Problems in this section}}}

\begin{document}

\section{intro}
\listproblems

\begin{problem}
 first problem
\end{problem}


\begin{problem}
 second problem
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
 another problem
\end{problem}

\section{another section}
\listproblems

\begin{problem}
 another problem
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
 another problem
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

It works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I had (since) realized about the write registers (see my comment above). Since posting I have modified my original code quite a lot, but I'm grateful for your answer, it looks very elegant.

Comment: @MatthewLeningang I think the answer I posted on your original question is the modified code I was talking about.