# Creating list of for \newtheoremstyle

Tags: table-of-contents, theorems, amsthm

I want to create an list of theorems much like the list of figures, but couldn't find a packacke or tutorial to solve my problem. I tried this http://texblog.org/2008/07/13/define-your-own-list-of/ but couldn't get it to work :-/

This is "my" theorem style:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}
  {\topsep}
  {\topsep}
  {}
  {}
  {\bfseries}
  {:}
  {\newline}
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}}
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a different approach using the kernel command `\@starttoc` (entries in the new list as formatted as standard subsections in `article`, but this can be easily modified):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}
  {\topsep}{\topsep}{}{}{\bfseries}{:}{\newline}
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}%
     \ifstrempty{#3}%
      {\addcontentsline{def}{subsection}{#1~\themydef}}%
      {\addcontentsline{def}{subsection}{#1~\themydef~(#3)}}}

\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\definitionname{Definition}
\newcommand\listdefinitionname{List of Definitions}
\newcommand\listofdefinitions{%
  \section*{\listdefinitionname}\@starttoc{def}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listofdefinitions

\begin{mydef}[A note]
\lipsum[2]
\end{mydef}

\begin{mydef}
\lipsum[2]
\end{mydef}

\begin{mydef}
\lipsum[2]
\end{mydef}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have a follow up question: Is there a way to remove the indent of the list?

Comment: Nevermind... it actually pretty simple. change the parameters of `\addcontentsline`

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution which basically

- adds a `contents` line to the file `\jobname.prb`
- reads that file with the command `\listmytheorems`

I've used the extension `.prb` simply because I've used in previous work

[Custom list of environments (per section)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23219/custom-list-of-environments-per-section)

I've used the `etoolbox` which provides many commands- the only one relevant to my code is `\ifstrempty`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}     % for theorems
\usepackage{lipsum}     % for sample text
\usepackage{etoolbox}   % \ifstrempty (and more)

% enable the \jobname.prb file
% (hacked from the ntheorem package)
\makeatletter%
\def\prb@enablelistofproblems{%
\begingroup%
\if@filesw%
\expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@prb\endcsname%
\immediate\openout \csname tf@prb\endcsname \jobname.prb\relax%
\fi%
\@nobreakfalse%
\endgroup}%

% enable the \jobname.prb files at the end
% of the document
\AtEndDocument{\prb@enablelistofproblems}%
\makeatother%

\newread\File
\def\listmytheorems{%
% open the \jobname.prb and read the contents
\par%
\openin\File=\jobname.prb%
\loop\unless\ifeof\File%
\read\File to\fileline%
\fileline%
\repeat%
\closein\File%
}%

% your theorem- with some tweaks
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}
  {\topsep}
  {\topsep}
  {}
  {}
  {\bfseries}
  {:}
  {\newline}
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}%
        \ifstrempty{#3}{\addcontentsline{prb}{section}{#1 \themydef}}{\addcontentsline{prb}{section}{#1 \themydef~(#3)}}
            }
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{List of my definitions}
\listmytheorems

\begin{mydef}[description goes here]
\lipsum[1]
\end{mydef}

\begin{mydef}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mydef}

\begin{mydef}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mydef}

\begin{mydef}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mydef}

\begin{mydef}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mydef}

\begin{mydef}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mydef}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could it be possible in case like `\begin{mydef}[description goes here]` to only have `description goes here` in the list of definitions ?

Comment: @projetmbc: And remove the preceding `Description X`?

Comment: What is the utility of one list containing `Definition 1`, `Definition 2`,... ? On the other hand, I think very usefull to have the list of important definitions and theorems in one course.

Comment: @projetmbc yes, change `{#1 \themydef~(#3)}` to `{#3}`

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, I've changed `\ifstrempty{#3}{\addcontentsline{prb}{section}{#1 \themydef}}{\addcontentsline{prb}{section}{#1 \themydef~(#3)}}` to `\ifstrempty{#3}{}{\addcontentsline{prb}{section}{#3}}`. That's perfect !

Comment: @projetmbc great. are you the same user as the OP? If so, it might avoid confusion to have a moderator merge your accounts

Comment: OP ? I don't understand.

Comment: @projetmbc OP means 'original poster'. So, is projetmbc the same person as 'distractedbysquirrels'

Comment: No, he's not :)