# Automated lists for todos in Latex document

Tags: table-of-contents, counters

When I write a document in Latex I usually use my custom `\todo{<my note>}`-command to not forget things that I will have to come back to. Something like

`\newcommand{\todo}[1]{{\color{red}\textbf{TODO:}~{#1}}}`

jumps into the eye well enough.

But I would like it even better, if I had a list of all todos that are sprinkled around a document. I.e. a command like `\todolist` that generates a list of all my todos (optionally with page and line info). Similar to a list of figures.

Since I am not an expert in Latex, I have troubles estimating the amount of work that I would have to be put into that. I would think I need a counter ... but what else? What other Latex building blocks are needed? :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't mention the `todo` or `todonotes` in your question, so if you want to do this using your own command, the following might be useful. The main part comes from Gonzalo's answer to

[Creating list of for \newtheoremstyle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51691/creating-list-of-for-newtheoremstyle/)

The code starts a new `toc` file, `\jobname.tod`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text

\newcounter{todo}
\newcommand\todo[1]{\refstepcounter{todo}\marginpar{\color{red}{#1}}\addcontentsline{tod}{subsection}{#1~\thetodo}}%


\makeatletter
\newcommand\todoname{todo}
\newcommand\listtodoname{List of todos}
\newcommand\listoftodos{%
  \section*{\listtodoname}\@starttoc{tod}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoftodos

\section{Main document}
\lipsum[1]\todo{fix this}

\lipsum[2]\todo{and this}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I had in mind! That is, until I had tried todonotes just now ...

Comment: What is the point of defining `\todoname`?

Answer (score 14):

The [documentation of todo](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/todo) (page 5) says:

> Command `\todos` prints the final list that gathers the todo text of all
>   the todos (except todoenv environments, that simply refer to the
>   text). Each item has a box, checkmarked when `\done`, the todo number,
>   and a reference (and interactive link if `hyperref` is on) to the page
>   where it appears.

The [documentation of todonotes](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/todonotes) (page 2) says:

> The `\listoftodos` command inserts a list of all the todos in the
>   current doc- ument. `\listoftodos` takes no arguments. For this document
>   the list of to–do’s looks like.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a package that already does this, I would recommend [`todonotes`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/todonotes/).  It has a number of configuration options, and may save you some effort getting to what you want.  Even if you are putting together something custom on your own, the source should be helpful in generating the lists.